# How to modify a method to be able to return multiple types instead of just `object`?

Tags: c#, methods, types, return

I have this method, and I'm convinced that it's the source of another issue I'm having. I believe it's because this method returns a type of `object` instead of one of the three concrete types it actually returns.

Here's the method:

```
public object GetData(TableType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case TableType.Person:
            return new Domain.PersonList(_personRepository.Get());
        case TableType.Event:
            return new Domain.EventList(_eventRepository.Get());
        case TableType.User:
            return new Domain.UserList(_userRepository.Get());
    }

    return null;
}
```

How can I modify this method to return a type other than `object`?

Comment: This is exact opposite of type-safety. You should replace your method with three properties.

Comment: A method can only have a single return type. What you are trying to do requires type-level metaprogramming capabilities that C# does not have.

Comment: @EduardoLeón Interesting. So is there no alternative that might do something similar to what I'm hoping for?

Comment: Maybe you could replace it with some generics: `public IList<T> GetData<T>()...`

Comment: @Magnus I've considered that, but had trouble figuring out how to implement it... I'll look into it, though. It seems like the best option at this point.

Comment: If these types have something in common you could use a common base class (other than object) or an interface.

Comment: @Magnus: That does not work either. C# generics cannot contain logic that depends on the concrete value of their type parameters.

Comment: @EduardoLeón What are you talking about?

Comment: @Magnus: Without using reflection, you cannot a generic method with type parameter `T` that branches depending on whether `T` is `Person`, `Event` or `User`.

Comment: @EduardoLeón Sure you can. `public IList<T> GetData<T>()
{
 if(typeof(T) == typeof(TblUser))
  return (IList<T>)db.TblUsers.ToList();
 if(typeof(T) == typeof(TblCompany))
  return (IList<T>)db.TblCompanies.ToList();
 return null;
}`

Comment: @Magnus: `typeof` relies on reflection.

Comment: @EduardoLeón Are you saying that c# code can not use reflection?  That seems to be an untenable position.

Comment: @PhilipRieck Of course C# code can use reflection, but, as with all extremely powerful features that break most of the safety guarantees of the language (you can use reflection to attempt to call methods that do not exist, set member variables that do not exist, and peek into the internals of a class that should be inaccessible from the outside world), reflection is not meant to be used casually.

Comment: @EduardoLeón I agree.  However perhaps saying "capabilities that C# does not have" is a bit misleading.

Comment: @PhilipRieck: C# does not have the capability to do what the OP wants in a type safe way. (Arguably, type safety is the whole point to this question. The OP wants the return type to be determined "cleverly" to avoid a downcast (downcasts are another type-unsafe feature!) in code calling this method.) In a properly designed language such as Haskell, this would be perfectly doable without sacrificing type safety.

Comment: @EduardoLeón  I see- you meant "c# sux", rather than "c# can't do this".   Reflection *can* be used here to do this in a type-safe way.  So could a base interface or different overall design of the underlying system.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39687/discussion-between-eduardo-leon-and-philip-rieck)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is to use Interfaces to guarantee that only one of your three types is returned.

```
public IDomainList GetData(TableType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case TableType.Person:
            return new Domain.PersonList(_personRepository.Get());
        case TableType.Event:
            return new Domain.EventList(_eventRepository.Get());
        case TableType.User:
            return new Domain.UserList(_userRepository.Get());
    }

    return null;
}
```

So long as `PersonList`, `EventList`, and `UserList` all implement the IDomainList interface, then you are guaranteed to return on of those three types. Then in your implementation, you can determine what to do based on the specific type returned.

Comment: The user of the `GetData` method would still be forced to downcast to the correct class, which is arguably what the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: True, but I think the core issue is that OP can't be guaranteed to downcast, as object could be anything. At least implementing an Interface requires these classes to share the Interface.

Comment: This actually worked for my situation. Sorry for any confusion, but this solves the problem. Thank you!

Comment: It works, but it is poor Object Oriented Design practice whenever you have a switch on a type.  You should let the compiler do that for you via inheritance and polymorphism.  Sometimes it can't be avoided, in which case you use the 'is' keyword and the 'as' keyword, or a cast.  But in your case you don't need any of this.  Use inheritance, or perhaps use interfaces in a way that do not involve switching on the type.

Comment: @philologon You are correct, it can definitely be improved on. -at kehrk Your welcome!

Answer (score 2):

What you need is generics.
This way the method will return the type according to `type`.

This method for example returns `TService` type:

```
private TService GetService<TService>(ServiceInfo serviceInfo)
    where TService : class, ICoordinationExecutionService
{
    var service = _executionServices.FirstOrDefault(
            x => x.ServiceInfo.InstanceInfo.InstanceId == serviceInfo.InstanceInfo.InstanceId
                && serviceInfo.ServiceTypeName.Equals(x.ServiceInfo.ServiceTypeName));

    if (service == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("invalid service ");
    }

    return _directory.GetService<TService>(service.ServiceInfo);
}
```

Comment: I was actually just going to look into a solution like this. I'll try it out, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, you must identify what is the "lowest common denominator" base class for the three kinds of repositories.  If you do not have one, then you should create one.  One way to do this would be

```
public abstract class repositoryBase
{
   public virtual IList<repositoryBase> Get() { }
}
```

Then each of the three classes woudl inherit from repositoryBase:

```
public personRepository : repositoryBase
{
   public override IList<personRepository> Get()
   {
      // code here to return the list
   }
}
```

Once you have refactored the class hierarchy in this way, then you don't even need the GetData method.  Where you were calling GetData, you now just call someRepository.Get();

If you are already inheriting from something else and adding a Get method to the base class is not a good fit, you can do the same thing I describe here using an Interface.  Either approach, base class or interface work equally well in this case and both are good OO practice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use generics to get this done,

```
public T GetData<T>()
{
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(Domain.PersonList))
        return new Domain.PersonList(_personRepository.Get());
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Domain.EventList))
        return new Domain.EventList(_eventRepository.Get());
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Domain.UserList))
        return new Domain.UserList(_userRepository.Get());
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create three `GetData` functions, that will get the type as a parameter and return the correct type.

```
public List<TableType.Person> GetData(TableType.Person type)
{
    return new Domain.PersonList(_personRepository.Get());
}

public List<TableType.Event> GetData(TableType.Event type)
{
     return new Domain.EventList(_eventRepository.Get());
}

public List<TableType.User> GetData(TableType.User type)
{
     return new Domain.UserList(_userRepository.Get());
}
```

The runtime will pick the correct overload according to the type of the parameter.

EDIT: I am assuming that the Domain.xxxxList functions return a list of the mentioned type in this example. It is not required, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a whole answer with a general solution for parameterized types for return value.

```
class Program
{
    public enum TableType
    {
        Person,
        Event,
        User
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Person(string name) { this.Name = name; }
    }
    class Event
    {
        public int EventType { get; set; }
        public Event(int eventType) { this.EventType = eventType; }
    }
    class User
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public User(string username) { this.UserName = username; }
    }

    public static T GetData<T>(TableType tableType)
    {
        switch (tableType)
        {
            case TableType.Person:
                Person person = new Person("John");
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(person, typeof(T));
            case TableType.Event:
                Event evt = new Event(2);
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(evt, typeof(T));
            case TableType.User:
                User user = new User("jjesus");
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(user, typeof(T));
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person person = GetData<Person>(TableType.Person);
        Console.WriteLine("Person.Name {0}", person.Name);

        Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```